# select like digits from rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a database of numbers. Four digit numbers to be exact. I want to see if any of them have like numbers in there.

So for instance a row might be 1232. I want to know that a double 2 came out. Is that possible using straight up postgresql?

I know there is `like %4%` which would find any 4's but only want 4s that came out twice. Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LIKE %4%4%
```

would find two `4`s

```
LIKE %44%
```

would find two consecutive `4`s